# Pycharm No tests found using pytest, pytest bdd

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, pytest

I have a problem: I'm trying create a test using pytest-bdd but I'm getting an error:

```
platform darwin -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-3.0.7, py-1.4.32, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /Users/harmatii/PycharmProjects/guru99/bdd, inifile:
plugins: bdd-2.18.2
collected 0 items / 1 errors

No tests found
```

Here is my code from 2 files:

```
Scenario Outline: Add New Customer
  Given a customer form
  When we fill out form with customer information <name>, <email>, <password>
  Then verify that page redirects to details of added customer


 Examples:
 |name    | |email          | |password |
 |Chris   | |hhh1@gmail.com | |password |
```

and my test file:

```
from pytest_bdd import scenario, given, when, then
from methods.customer import *
from methods.login import *
from methods.is_present import *


@scenario('customers.feature', 'Add New Customer')
def test_customers():
    pass


@given('a customer form')
def customer_form(driver):
    login(driver, username="mngr91344", password="ubymYtA")


@when('we fill out form with customer information <name>, <email>, <password>')
def add_customer(driver):
    add_new_customer(driver, name="Chris", email="hhh1@gmail.com", password="password")


@then('verify that page redirects to details of added customer')
def verify_page(driver):
    is_element_present(driver, By.LINK_TEXT, "Customer Registered Successfully!!!")
```

Other regular tests (without bdd) in the same project run without a problem.

Comment: what is your test file name? it should be prefix `test_` like `test_file_name.py`

Comment: it is, test_customers_steps.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

py.test reports 1 error is found:

```
ValueError: In "parametrize" the number of values (['Chris', '', 'hhh1@gmail.com', '', 'password']) must be equal to the number of names (['name', 'email', 'password'])
```

Remove the empty columns from the Examples section of `customers.feature`:

```
 Examples:
 |name    |email          |password |
 |Chris   |hhh1@gmail.com |password |
```

Then test collection is successful:

```
$ py.test --collect-only
=========================== test session starts ===========================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.2, pytest-3.2.1, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /home/they4kman/.virtualenvs/tmp-5ce0cdbde232a4e/src, inifile:
plugins: bdd-2.18.2
collected 1 item                                                           
<Module 'test_customer_steps.py'>
  <Function 'test_customers[Chris-hhh1@gmail.com-password]'>
```

Comment: yeah it was problem too, but error "no test found" for some reason was because of version pytest, i updated it to pytest-3.2.1 like yours and it gave me ValueError: In "parametrize"
Thank you for help